# Django DateTimePicker only shows up for superusers inside my app

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, datetimepicker, django-widget

I'm using django DateTimePicker widget -- AdminSplitDateTime() -- in event creating app, every thing goes fine when the loged in user has superuser permissions, but when normal user tries to access the creating form the widget don't show up.

I don't know why it acts like this? and how to overcome this behavior?

this is the the scripts included in my page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/actions.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js"></script>
```

her is my form code

```
class Form(ModelForm):
    """

    """

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        exclude = ('creator')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['start'].widget = widgets.AdminSplitDateTime()
        self.fields['end'].widget = widgets.AdminSplitDateTime()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `/admin/jsi18n/` is unaccessible for non-staff users. You should add a JS script before the first widget and define there some vars:

```
var catalog = {}
function pluralidx(count) { return (count == 1) ? 0 : 1; }
function gettext(msgid) { return msgid; }
function ngettext(singular, plural, count) { return count == 1 ? singular : plural; }
function gettext_noop(msgid) { return msgid; }
function interpolate(fmt, obj, named) {
  if (named) {
    return fmt.replace(/%\(\w+\)s/g, function(match){return String(obj[match.slice(2,-2)])});
  } else {
    return fmt.replace(/%s/g, function(match){return String(obj.shift())});
  }
}
```

These are taken from django's `/admin/jsi18n/` under admin user.

P.S. You can find JS errors in JS console of your browser, it may give you the direction.